# Problem with JQueryUI Sortable: serialize reporting the wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using `sortable` to implement a one-dimensional list of widgets. It's working alright, but when I call `serialize` to send the current order back to the server, the wrong order is generated.

Here's my HTML, note the ordering of widget IDs: 13, 10, 11:

```
<div id="widget_columns">
    <ul id="column1" class="widget-column grid_8 alpha ui-sortable">
        <li id="widget_13" class="widget">
        (a widget!)
        </li>

        <li id="widget_10" class="widget">
        (a widget!)
        </li>

        <li id="widget_11" class="widget">
        (a widget!)
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The list is initialized with

```
    $(#widget_columns').sortable({
        connectWith: $(#widget_columns'),
        handle: settings.handleSelector,
        placeholder: 'widget-placeholder',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        revert: 300,
        delay: 100,
        opacity: 0.8,
        containment: 'document',
        start: function (e, ui) {
            $(ui.helper).addClass('dragging');
        },
        stop: function (e, ui) {
            $(ui.item).css({ width: '' }).removeClass('dragging');
            $(settings.columns).sortable('enable');
        }
    });
```

However, when I then call

```
alert($('#widget_columns *').sortable('serialize'));
```

to find out the widget order, I get the correct IDs, but in the wrong order, 10, 11, 13:

```
widget[]=10&widget[]=11&widget[]=13
```

Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying the `sortable` method on the parent div and not the `ul` I'm not sure why, also when calling `serialize` you are not calling it on the previous *sortable* object!

Here is a small *working* [example](http://jsfiddle.net/XShQY/1/):

```
$('#column1').sortable({
    //connectWith: $('#widget_columns'),
    revert: 300,
    delay: 100,
    opacity: 0.8,
    containment: 'document',
    start: function(e, ui) {
        //$(ui.helper).addClass('dragging');
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        //$(ui.item).css({ width: '' }).removeClass('dragging');
        //$(settings.columns).sortable('enable');
        alert($(this).sortable('serialize'))
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code works, mine* still doesn't... Guess it's back to debugging for me. :-/

* my production code. The simple version I posted above works.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, it has something to do with the fact that my solution `disable`s the sortable whenever dragging ends, and `enable`s it when dragging starts, a concept I unthinkingly took from some tutorial. When I removed the code disabling and re-enabling the sortable (`$(settings.columns).sortable('disable');`), the serialization worked fine.